# how to make a navigation such as this

Tags: jquery, html

I stumbled upon this site http://nathanborror.com/ and really loved the way they have done the navigation on the left hand site.  I noticed that site is using jquery but didnt see any plugins.

Any ideas on how to go about doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They have it within the [bootstrap.js](http://media.nathanborror.com/javascript/bootstrap.js) file, essentially it's simple [jQuery.hover()](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/hover#overout) with a [jQuery.animate()](http://docs.jquery.com/Effects/animate#paramsdurationeasingcallback) nested.

Answer (score 2):

First, set your menu to use "top","left" and "position" css atributes, so it always stick to the left. Then, use jquery to do the animations on hover, like this :

```
$('#menu .item').hover(
      function () {
        $(this).animate({width:'toggle'},350); // end value
      }, 
      function () {
        $(this).animate({width:'toggle'},100); // start value
      }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

It's probably pretty easy to find out by looking at [their source code](http://media.nathanborror.com/javascript/bootstrap.js). If you want to see what's running, use [Firebug](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/1843).